# Processing text stream sections, separated by ␁

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, xargs, posix

How can I split a file stream that is on `stdin` into smaller sections that each get passed to a script,

I have a large file that is on `stdin` that resembles...

```
␁HeadingHere
abcd
abcd
␁Different Title
bcde
bcde
{a lot longer}
␁Different again!
cdef
cdef
```

I am after a way of passing each of these sections to `./script.sh`

which would simulate doing:

```
cat <<EOF | ./script.sh
␁HeadingHere
abcd
abcd
EOF
```

---

```
cat <<EOF | ./script.sh
␁Different Title 
bcde
bcde
{a lot longer}
EOF
```

---

```
cat <<EOF | ./script.sh
␁Different again!
cdef
cdef
EOF
```

Each section can be determined by a `␁` separating them.

I thought of using `xargs` and doing something along the lines of  `xargs -d '\01' -n1 echo` but run into `xargs: argument line too long`

Ideally the script will be `posix` compliant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the sections to separate files and process them one-by-one. This would produce `outfile.1` etc:

```
awk '/^␁/ { count++ } { print > "outfile." count }  ' < file
```

Or, you could have `awk` pipe the sections one-by-one to a command:

```
awk  'BEGIN {command = "./script.sh"} /^␁/ { close(command) }
      { print | command } ' < file
```

---

I used the literal U+2401 SYMBOL FOR START OF HEADING in the above, as that's what copy-pasting gave me. You used `\01` in the `xargs` command line, so if that's what you have, change the SOH squiggle to the actual START OF HEADING, `\001` in the `awk` code, too.

---

We could also set `RS` to the SOH but that doesn't fit quite exactly, since here we have the SOH at the start of the record, and `awk` expects to find the record separator at the end.

Comment: `awk` really is a powerful tool, I had no idea you can pipe stuff like that in it

Comment: @jamesmstone, frankly, me neither.

Comment: dont you need to change `RS` here? since `print | command` is just pass a single line (Heading only) when that starts with  `/^␁/` not whole block

Comment: @αғsнιη, mm, no, it seemed to work as far as I tested. The way I understood it, `awk` keeps the pipe open, in the same as it does for files. So it's not closed and reopened after each `print`, but only when we explicitly call `close()`. Though yeah, we could also change `RS`. But then we see a zero-length record at the beginning of the file and it gets a bit awkward. Well, at least I like the line-based approach more.

Comment: Ah, Yes I didn't read carefully enough that `/^␁/` is for `close(command)` not the `print` one. but lines feeding into the command one by one instead of whole block at once  (I doubt if OP wants line by line for each block or whole each block at a time)

Answer (score 1):

If the source file does not have empty lines (two consecutive newlines), you can convert each of the `␁` into two newlines with sed. That will create a file (or stream) that has an empty line as the delimiter of each record. Then, awk (with an empty RS) is able to separate each "empty line" delimited file (stream) into "records".

The description may sound complex, but look at the code:

```
sed 's/␁/\n\n/g' file | awk -v RS='' -vf="./script" '{print|f;close(f)}'
```

If you actually need to convert a character that has a byte value of 0x01, then replace `␁` with `\x01` in the sed command.